# modular arithmetic $ax=b$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am familiar with finding solution to $ax=b$ in $\mathbb{Z_m}$ , but how could I know whether there is more than 1 solution?

For example solving $83x=2$ in $\mathbb{Z_{321}}$ I have found $x=205$ but is there anymore? like in $2x=4$ where we get $x=2$ or $x=5$ in $\mathbb{Z_6}$.
Thanks

Comment: note that in $\mathbb{Z}_m$ that if $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ then we have $a(x+km) = ax + akm = ax$. So straight off the bat, if $x$ is a solution then the set $\{ x + km | k \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ is also a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ax \equiv b \bmod m$ has a solution iff $d=\gcd(a,m)$ divides $b$.

In this case, all solutions come from solving $a'x \equiv b' \bmod m'$, where $a=da'$, $b=db'$, $m=dm'$.

Now, $\gcd(a',m')=1$ and so $a'x \equiv b' \bmod m'$ has exactly one solution $x_0$ mod $m'$, which can be found with the extended Euclidean algorithm.

The original equation thus has exactly $d$ solutions mod $m$, given by $x_0+t m'$, for $t=0,\dots, d-1$.

Comment: so is it the case that gcd(a,m)=number of solutions?

Comment: but then lets say 6x=4 in z10 gives us 1 though

Comment: @Rivaldo, $\gcd(6,10)=2$, and two solutions: $x=4$ and $x=9$.